# Android: RESTful JDBC Proxy. Performance and Security

Tags: java, android, mysql, rest, jdbc

We wanted to use cloud backend for storing Android app data.
Our backend RDBMS is famous MySQL server which comes with MySQL Connector/J (an Official MySQL Network JDBC Adapter which can connect to remote MySQL database).

Now the problem is we cannot use this MySQL Connector/J in Android as its not developed for android. So what we did is, we created a REST class with four rest methods /query, /insert, /update, /delete. All these methods takes JSON Object which is wrapping parameters of respective Android ContentProvider methods. /query rest method returns a tabular resultset data in JSON format.

Then we wrote Android ContentProvider which is acting as a proxy to call our above rest methods. ContentProvider.query() method calls /query rest method and converts the received resultset JSON into Cursor for returning it.

With this architecture our server code become generic without having any business logic. And our Android app is unaware of whether the data is coming from cloud server or local database. Practically all this is working fine.

So the question is how much secure this architecture is? from the hacking point of view. And what will be the impact on Android App performance? Please help us with your valuable comments/answers.

Comment: We can't possibly answer that without inspecting all your code, which makes this question too broad. Hire a software security company to review and audit your software.

Answer (score 0):

You not should connect directly from Android app to Database (MySQL), it will give you not good performance. 
I recommend for you buid Webservice API which will connect to Database and fetch, hence from Android app connect and fetch data from Webservice.
I hope this helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody can decompile your code, find this service and if he breaks your service security he can do nasty things with your database. He can browse your database, steal data, corrup data .. Crackers are searching for SQL injection on web - and you are providing direct database access.

Do not do that. Create a service for each use case that will validate/escape parameters and then call prepared JDBC statement.